# Google Maps API only shows one user location, but multiple user locations are saved on Firebase (Kotlin android app)

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I created an app with Google Maps API as a home page, and users are able to register accounts using Realtime Firebase Database. The tree stores all users' location separately under each UID, like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- users
       |
       --- $uid
            |
            --- profileImageUrl: "https://..."
            |
            --- uid: "h9xZs...bV82"
            |
            --- username: "My name"
            |
            --- location
                  |
                  --- latitude: 53.37...
                  |
                  --- longitude: -0.90...
```

This is how the code looks currently looks like for this problem:

```
private fun getLocationUpdates() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest()
        locationRequest.interval = 30000
        locationRequest.fastestInterval = 20000
        locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                if (locationResult.locations.isNotEmpty()) {
                    val location = locationResult.lastLocation



                    //save each user`s location to firebase database

                    val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    val databaseRef: DatabaseReference = Firebase.database.reference
                    val locationlogging = LocationLogging(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                    databaseRef.child("users").child(user!!.getUid()).child("userlocation").setValue(locationlogging)

                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Locations written into the database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error occured while writing your location to the database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }


                    //show marker on map

                    val latLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                    val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
                    map.addMarker(markerOptions)
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10f))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If I log in, I can only see one location, which is my own device location. However, if I also log in using another device at the same time, the marker not showing up.

I was suggested putting my code into a for each loop, so it reads all longitudes and latitudes from Firebase until all appear on the map.

How do I make my app show all locations, so each user can see each other's location?

Comment: How do you read the other user locations?

Comment: That is the question. It only reads the own location and cannot see the other user locations.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data), or at least a screenshot.

Comment: https://ibb.co/XV7nrmc

Answer (score 0):

According to your database [schema](https://ibb.co/XV7nrmc), to get the locations of all users, please use the following lines of code:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val usersRef = rootRef.child("users")
usersRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        for (userSnapshot in task.result!!.children) {
            val lat = userSnapshot.child("userlocation/latitude").getValue(Double::class.java)!!
            val lng = userSnapshot.child("userlocation/longitude").getValue(Double::class.java)!!
            Log.d(TAG, "$lat, $lng")
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, task.exception!!.message!!) //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
}
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
53.82809, -1.6617683
...
```

Now having the coordinates of all users, you can add the corresponding markers on the Google Map.